# Error even after throws Exception for thread.sleep

Tags: java

I am trying to make my Thread sleep and am making the method throws InterruptedException, however it is still giving the error "Unhandled exception"

```
  @Before
    public void setUp() throws InterruptedException{

        simulatorList.forEach(simulation -> {
           ....
            Thread.sleep(1000*60*1);
//giving error here 

            ...
        });
}
```

Comment: Your question   is not clear. What is the expectation here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you calling Thread.sleep inside foreach, Below will solve your issue:

```
public void setUp() throws InterruptedException {
    List<String> simulatorList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : simulatorList) {
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause exception can be thrown from lambda. The easiest way to handle it is to rethrow the RuntimeException. like

```
public void setUp(){

    new LinkedList<String>().forEach(simulation -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000*60*1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
}
```

If you really expect for `InterruptedException`, you can create your own exception extending `RuntimeException`, like `RuntimeInterruptedException`, rethrow it and then handle in your flow.